# IE11 renders Asian characters lower than other browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, asianfonts

I'm working on a site for work and we support many languages. For some reason, IE11 seems to want to render Asian characters (especially Korean) lower than other languages when using line-height. I have an element that I want to vertically center my text in that is 21px high and I set a line-height of 21px on it. This works across all browsers and languages except for Asian languages in IE11. Is there a way to remedy this via CSS (other than manually changing the line-height for these languages) that would work cross-browser?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/XiajYGe.png]

Here is an example of how it is rendering in IE11, but centers in other browsers.

Comment: you have any html or css code to demo the problem?

Comment: That image site just loads forever... any other way to show the image? Also, can you show the code that you are using?

Comment: @Guffa I updated the image link with an imgur one.

Comment: Post a code example of the problem that is relevant.

Comment: I think I found part of the problem. It seems that higher up the chain there's a style on it setting `font-family: Arial, sans-serif;` It seems that IE11 is getting the font as sans-serif, and this is causing the text to be pushed down. Here's a jsFiddle of code: http://jsfiddle.net/ymL2m03n/2/

You can see in Chrome it looks centered correctly, but in IE11 it's pushed down. Is there a way to have it render similarly across browsers?

Comment: It actually renders just fine in IE11 on my computer.

Comment: It's possible that your computer natively supports Arial, and it seems that mine isn't, therefor it gets the sans-serif for the font-family. If you go to this fiddle (I changed it to just be sans-serif), does it still look vertically centered in IE11? http://jsfiddle.net/ymL2m03n/3/